# How do I find out which users have permissions to add/remove other users?

Tags: role-management

From what I understand, There are 3 base roles which can do this:

1. Sitecore Local Administrators
2. Sitecore Client Securing
3. Sitecore Client Account Managing

So I suppose if I want to get the roles which inherit from these base roles I'll do a query to my database consisting partly of this:
[image]

After to find out which users have this I'll do another query on the Users Database to find out which users have these rights.

ANYWAYS, I suppose the question is really then which base roles have permissions to add/remove other users from sitecore?

Comment: As a note, do not forget that users with the admin checkbox can also manipulate user accounts. You may want to include those too!

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore Client Account Managing is the right role to add/remove users.

From Sitecore Documentation :

> Gives the user access to maintain users, roles, and domains in the
> Access Manager, the Domain Manager, the Role Manager, and the User
> Manager.

https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/the-security-roles.html

To view the members of this Role open Sitecore Client Account Managing role in user manager and click Members:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no OOTB functionality to get users that can remove other users, but you can use some workarounds.

I suggest using an API call below to check if you have enough permissions to call the User Manager application for the current user:

```
SecurityHelper.CanRunApplication("Security/User Manager");
```

Then you can go through all users and you can use a similar code to check if the specified user can open the application:

```
List<Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User> powerUsers = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserManager.GetUsers()
    .Where(user => CanRunApplication("Security/User Manager", user))
    .ToList();

public static bool CanRunApplication([CanBeNull] string applicationName, [CanBeNull] Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User user)
{
    if (user == null 
        || applicationName.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!applicationName.StartsWith("/", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
    {
        applicationName = "/sitecore/content/Applications/" + applicationName;
    }

    using (new UserSwitcher(user))
    {
        Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item;
        using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
        {
            item = Sitecore.Client.CoreDatabase.GetItem(applicationName);
        }

        return item != null && item.Access.CanRead();
    }
}
```

**Few points to highlight there:**

1. Actually, if you have read permissions to "/sitecore/content/Applications/Security/User Manager" item, then you can call this application.
2. "New" and "Delete" buttons are always enabled.

*So, if you have permission to open this application then you can create/delete users.*

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore OOTB Role to maintain user is **Sitecore Client Account Managing**. So to check who all can manage user, we should be checking which all users are associated with this role.

Role: **Sitecore Client Account Managing**
Gives the user access to maintain users, roles, and domains in the Access Viewer, the Domain Manager, the Role Manager, and the User Manager applications.

**Steps to check list of user having part of this role**

- Click on Role Manager on Launchpad
- Select sitecore\Sitecore Client Account Managing
- Click on Members from the Menu

[image]

https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/101/platform-administration-and-architecture/the-security-roles.html